# Can I add a Decimate modifier on all of the objects at once?

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, vertices, faces

My project has over 7 million vertices, 6 million faces and 12 million tris's.

I'm also new to rendering but it's slowing down my project A LOT.

My scene has a lot of leaves and grass and I bet they are the ones that have a lot of the polygons and are the ones who causes the slowness.

My animation is 800 frames long, and each frame takes ~2-3 minutes to render...

I looked for solutions in the internet, there were some options like: Decimate Geometry; select all vertices and give them a Limited Dissolve option; and for triangle reduction I should do Ctrl+T.

Problem is, there are way too many objects to click and apply these settings manually, is there any way around this? Or maybe there is an add-on that does it all even better?

Comment: no I tried this long before you even posted it. When I try to Ctrl+L - copy the modifier onto other ones it doesn't work, in fact it even removed the modifier from the main object that was supposed to "spread" it to other objects. Also the trick with Alt key pressing didn't even do nothing, the post is probably too old for the newest version.

Comment: Did you "select the object(s) to apply the modifier to then the one that has the modifier" like the answers suggested? Selection order matters.

Comment: Eh, ok here is what I did: I clicked on a object, gave it a modifier, then I selected objects that need that modifier, and the last object I selected is the one that has the modifier, and then Ctrl+L it, no effects. I double checked, the outline for the last object is in yellow, do I need to apply the mod first?

Comment: hey what gives >:( my question got closed just because the same old solutions don't work with today, in 2020? Can anyone even see this anymore or is it how it works here - if it doesn't solve anything, we close it and ask it again, even though it's going to be the same question??

Comment: There is an addon called "Copy attributes menu". It has an option (on pressing Ctrl+C) "Copy selected modifiers". It does exactly what you want.

Comment: And there is indeed this answer (by satishgoda) in the thread on link in the header. =)

Comment: I assure you that answer still works - I've just tried it. If it's not working then maybe the objects you're selecting aren't meshes?

Comment: @Mechanic LOL thank you a lot, I always think that confirmed solutions on the posts are the ones I should always look at, I rarely even bother looking at other un-verified solutions. Anyway this worked and it's a lot easier than what I have mentioned, thanks!

Comment: to avoid such great numbers (polycount) look over some tuts how to deal with particle system for creating grass and leaves. Duplicated instances are waaay faster to render and view in the viewport. And the memory is used much better. I mean future projects, of course. for this there is nothing that one can do =)

Comment: @Mechanic sure, I just really wanted to try 3D modelling out and I'm giving all of my best to it because I love it. And since the project is for my university and I'm nearing to a deadline, I keep asking a lot of questions, especially when I'm new with everything. Thanks for the tips and encouragement! Be safe.